# Can't retrieve Web page via VBScript unless opened in browser first

Tags: vbscript

I want to retrieve and process some Web pages with VBScript, which is being run from the command line.  It bears mentioning that I'm on a work computer, and "some setting are managed by your system administrator".  Also, I log in to the computer with a CAC, so (and I think this is the problem) there are certificates involved.

My problem is that, frequently, when I run the VBScript I'll get back a 401/unauthorized error, for both HTTPS and non-HTTPS sites.  If I then open the URL in a browser, the script (still being run from the command line) will work.  If I run the script on my home computer I can always access any URL without first having to open it in a browser.  So, I'm guessing it has to do with either the certificates in my CAC (which are also installed on the computer), or some other certificate on the computer, that are used to authenticate the connection (or some such thing).

My question is:  how can I retrieve various Web pages using VBScript (without installing any additional software) without having to first open the URL in a browser to get the script to work?

Here is my code for getting a Web page, if that helps:

```
function getWebPage(sURL)
    dim iErrorCount

    on error resume next
    '******************
    'ERROR CHECKING OFF
    '******************
    oHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
    oHTTP.Send

    if (err.number <> 0) then
        iErrorCount = 0

        do
            iErrorCount = iErrorCount + 1

            log "log.txt", "Error retrieving Web page. Error #0x" & hex(err.number) & ". Description: " & err.description, 0, true

            if (iErrorCount = 5) then
                log "log.txt", vbTab & "Five successive errors retrieving Web page. Exiting...", 1, true
                msgbox "ERROR: Five successive errors retrieving " & chr(34) & sURL & chr(34) & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "See the log file for details." & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "Exiting...", vbOkOnly, programName

                log "last result.html", oHTTP.ResponseText, 0, false

                wscript.quit
            else
                wscript.sleep iErrorCount * 60000

                set oHTTP = nothing
                set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

                oHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
                oHTTP.Send
            end if
        loop until (err.number = 0)
    end if
    on error goto 0
    '*****************
    'ERROR CHECKING ON
    '*****************

    if (oHTTP.Status <> 200) then
        log "log.txt", vbcrlf & vbtab & "Error retrieving Web page" & vbcrlf & vbtab & "URL: " & sURL & vbcrlf & vbtab & "Status: " & oHTTP.Status & vbcrlf & vbtab & "Description: " & oHTTP.statusText, 1, true
        msgbox "ERROR: Cannot retrieve Web page." & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "See the log file for details." & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "Exiting...", vbOkOnly, programName

        wscript.quit
    else
    '   log "last result.html", oHTTP.ResponseText, 0, false
        getWebPage = oHTTP.ResponseText
    end if
end function
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the url exactly right with xmlhttp object. Run this code and print out the error messages (you can copy a messagebox with Ctrl + C).

```
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
 On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/Softlib/README.TXT", False
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
    line =""
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error getting file" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "==================" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf &  File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo Line
    Err.clear
    wscript.quit
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\safetyscanner.exe", 2
```

Comment: After you run above program with your URL and paste the results. D/l fiddler from http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configurefiddler and log both a working and non working connnection.

Comment: You also don't show the object you are using in your code. You create it at the end but not to begin with. Any way here are a fewother objectsto try HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP.1.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0